# I have two i2c devices. Both alone work well, but when I read from one, and then write to the other, the second one is not an ancknowledging

Tags: i2c, mbed, mpu6050

I have two devices MPU6050 and EEPROM 24C256. I can write and read from both alone. But when I try to read from MPU6050 and than write data to EEPROM in the same session, the EEPROM does not respond. I am using mbed OS libraries. And my question is.. Is it library, code or hardware problem?

MPU6050 read sequence: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRo9U.png)

EEPROM write page sequance:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTYYP.png)

//CODE

```
const char imuAddress = 0x68<<1;
const char imuDataAddress = 0x3B;
const char eepAddress = 0xA0;
const char data[3] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
char acc[3];

//reading acceleration data from IMU
    while(true){
        i2c.start();
        if(i2c.write(imuAddress) != 1){
            i2c.stop();
            continue;
        }
        if(i2c.write(imuDataAddress) != 1){
            i2c.stop();
            continue;
        }
        i2c.start();
        if(i2c.write(imuAddress | 0x01) != 1){
            i2c.stop();
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            i2c.read(1);   //read and respond ACK to continue
        }
        i2c.read(0);   //read and respond NACK to stop reading
        i2c.stop();
        break;
    }
//write data to EEPROM
    while(true){
            i2c.start();
            if(i2c.write(eepAddress) != 1){   //here is the problem (EEPROM does not respond)
                i2c.stop();
                continue;
            }
            if(i2c.write(0x00) != 1){
                i2c.stop();
                continue;
            }
            if(i2c.write(0x00) != 1){
                i2c.stop();
                continue;
            }
            bool ack = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                if(i2c.write(data[i]) != 1){
                    i2c.stop();
                    ack = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ack == true){
                i2c.stop();
                break;    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple initial thoughts, but do you have access to an oscilloscope? It is odd that each one works individually.  This makes me think that it may be an issue between the transition. (Possibly try a delay between each one? Also, possibly remove the stops in the initial read as they aren't necessary)

I think the best way to figure this out is to post a scope trace of the messaging for each one running individually and a trace of them running back to back.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can use an oscilloscope at university, but nowadays it is not simple to get there. I have already trie to put delay in between, but there is no change. Your recomendation with removing stop has the same result. But I have realized that it does not matter which device I want to access as the sedond one. I tried the same code and in the second write access not to access EEPROM but IMU again and it is not working too. So I think the problem would be stopping readings from IMU. Is it possible that it tries to sends more data even if I send a NACK and stop condition?

Comment: Ok, I have one more IMU so I tried change them and everything works properly. It seems to be some hardware fault in the first IMU.